# Getting Attempted import error while building the code in my React App

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Getting the below error.

Attempted import error: 'internal_processStyles' is not exported from '@mui/styled-engine' (imported as 'processStyles').

I have checked the code there is nothing got added from our(dev) side still getting this. it was working fine yesterday. Now out of blue we are getting this. Do anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Hi Pankaj. Welcome to SO. Please provide us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help you. For example looking at your `package.json` file would go a long way toward solving the problem.

Comment: Did you able to solve it? I am facing the same issue.